# Add XAML Vector Graphics in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I converted a .svg file to .xaml with inkscape and the resulting file is a canvas. I added the whole canvas to a Resource in a file ImageResources.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"> 
<Canvas x:Key="xamltest" Name="svg2" Width="9354.3341" Height="5977.5567"> 
<Canvas.RenderTransform> 
    <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
...
...
...
</Canvas>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then I merge the resource files to the resource dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/AP_PlugIn;component/Resources/BrushLists.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/AP_PlugIn;component/Resources/System/ConverterResources.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/AP_PlugIn;component/Resources/ImageResources.xaml"/>

  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Finally I try to display the canvas in a Grid with a ContentControl but the Image is not appearing. What could be wrong? I get no error and my Project starts correctly

```
<Grid>
<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource xamltest}" Width="1253" Height="637"  /> 
</Grid>
```

Comment: Your image is 9000x6000 pixels and your ContentControl size is 1200x600 pixels. I would guess the upper left 1200x600 pixels of your image are empty and this is why don't see anything.

Answer (score 0):

The Canvas seems to be a lot larger than the area provided by the ContentControl.

You may use Viewbox instead, which scales its child element:

```
<Viewbox Child="{StaticResource xamltest}" Width="1253" Height="637"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the dimensions of the Canvas, I suspect that the visible portion of the image is being drawn off the screen.

Try swapping the canvas for a grid, without specifying its size.

The following minimal proof of concept works fine

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Key="MyImage">
        <Path
            Data="M 0,0 M 100,100 M 25,50 L 50,25 L 75,50 L 50,75 z"
            Stretch="Fill"
            Stroke="Blue"
            StrokeThickness="5" />
        <Path
            Data="M 0,0 M 100,100 M 25,25 L 25,75 L 75,75 L 75,25 z"
            Stretch="Fill"
            Stroke="Black"
            StrokeThickness="10" />
    </Grid>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid
    Margin="16"
    Background="AliceBlue">

    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource MyImage}" />

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions from Clemens and Peregrine work good with simple canvas like the one Peregrine posted or small icons I found in the web, but it is not working with the big file a got after conversion. I think the problem lies with the file thrown by inkScape. I removed most of the lines of the xaml image and some parts are displayed. It is difficult to find the problem because I am not using visual Studio, am using another plattform called VisiWin and there is no way to debug. Have you worked with xaml files converted with inkScape?